# Simple rate limiter in Servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets

I have developed a simple counter based rate limiter in the first java servlet filter for my multi tenant application.

Its just does not allow maximum requests to exceed my configured limits for e.g. don't allow to have total requests more than 750.

Also have limits per tenant for e.g. 5 requests per tenant.

I know its a very rate limiter but seems to protect against system going down against DDOS because at no point of time number of requests goes beyond the accepted number of threads in my tomcat container.

My calls are all synchronous and blocking, so the HTTP thread just executes the task in its own thread and no delegation to application thread pool happens.

So i understand that if i protect the application on HTTP requests level then i am at least fine in case of DDOS attacks.

Is there any way my application could go down due to DDOS attacks (obviously assuming that application logic coding was fine )?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: What type of application server are you using (tomcat, wildfly, Jetty)?

Comment: @CarlitosWay thanks for looking into this...i am on tomcat